# Repace class completely when using Jquery toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the codes below to toggle 2 classes when I click a button.

```
<button class="filter-btn-open">Open</button>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.filter-btn-open').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("filter-btn-close" );
    });
});
```

The issue I am facing is that the `filter-btn-open` class is not completely removed. `filter-btn-close` is added and removed when the button is toggled but `filter-btn-open` is always retained. How can it be completely removed and replaced on toggle?

**Just more clarification**

On click, I get this - `<button class="filter-btn-open filter-btn-close">Open</button>`
When clicked again, it returns back to `<button class="filter-btn-open">Open</button>` and goes on like that. As you can see, the `filter-btn-open` class is always there.
When click, I want `<button class="filter-btn-open">Open</button>` to become `<button class="filter-btn-close">Open</button>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Should add the classes that are to be toggled

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.filter-btn-open').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("filter-btn-close filter-btn-open" );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="filter-btn-open">Open</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I did not know I had to repeat the initial class

Answer (score 2):

No where in your code are your removing/toggling the open class.
You need to toggle both.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.filter-btn-open').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("filter-btn-close filter-btn-open");
    });
});
```